# Как присвоить созданному в программе файлу иконку самой программы?

Tags: delphi

То есть другими словами (судя по принятому ответу) - Как ассоциировать расширение файлов, создаваемых в программе, с программой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вам надо ассоциировать расширение файлов, создаваемых в Вашей программе, с вашей программой.

Например, [вот здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/630ed1d9-73f1-4cc0-bc84-04f29cffc13b/what-registry-keys-are-responsible-for-file-extension-association?forum=netfxbcl) есть достаточно развернутый ответ (на английском):

> Выполните эти шаги, чтобы создать новую ассоциацию файлов:
>
> 1. Откройте в реестре Windows раздел `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` и создайте ключ для расширения файла (если он еще не существует).
> 2. Откройте ключ и запишите в параметр `DefaultValue` имя вашего обработчика, например `MyApp_ext`.
> 3. Закройте данный ключ и создайте другой ключ в разделе `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` совпадающий с именем вашего обработчика
>      (`MyApp_ext`).
> 4. Откройте этот ключ и запишите в параметр `DefaultValue` описание этого расширения.
> 5. Создайте в текущем ключе ключ `DefaultIcon`.
> 6. Откройте ключ и запишите в параметр `DefaultValue` полный путь к файлу с иконкой.
> 7. Закройте ключ и создайте ключи `\shell\Open\Command` в ключе-обработчике (`MyApp_ext`).
> 8. Откройте его и запишите в параметр `DefaultValue` полный путь к приложению, включая аргументы командной строки.

Или просто посмотрите ветку реестра `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, как хранятся ассоциации для других программ.

Answer (score 2):

Плохо искали. Ветка реестра `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` отвечает в том числе за выбор программы для открытия файлов и их иконки. В частности, параметр `DefaultIcon` устанавливает иконку. Посмотрите как у вас эта секция устроена и сделайте так же.